# Cloudflare DNS PTR Record Issue with Specific Email Providers

Tags: email, pointers, dns, smtp, cloudflare

we have a problem that after activating Cloudflare, some of our emails are not sent to certain email providers like freenet.de we recieve the folloing log:

......@freenet.de: host emig.freenet.de[195.4.92.216] said:
550-Inconsistent/Missing DNS PTR record (RFC 1912 2.1)
(k76a17.meinserver.io) 550 [148.251.209.167]:51009 (in reply to RCPT TO
command)

[Our dns config on Cloudflare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYqGZ.png)

We tried troubleshooting the email settings related to Cloudflare and made some changes, but it didn't resolve our issue. Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.